# Auto play after site fully loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, vimeo

Okay don't bash me but...

Is there a way to autoplay a vimeo video via iframe 'Only' after the entire website is fully loaded? I'm going to assume javascript/jquery but that's just a thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jquery you can do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("iframe", { 
       src: ''
       ..
     }).appendTo("#myDiv");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to use this: http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api

And you'll probably need to put your code in the `window.onload` event in order to ensure that the entire page loads before it begins playing.